# dealing with spaces in filenames and paths when compare local files to remote files (and delete remote if same)

Tags: bash, shell

The target directories should be variables, but that is an easy fix later. The target directories are locally (where the command is run from) and remote ("/home/user/somepath/"). Compare all files in target directories and subdirs and delete the remote ones on a match. Not sue if it actually looks at files in the target dirs themselves, but that can be dealt with later. Ideally this would compare more than 1 layer deep, but can recursively call if need be from within the subdirs. Or maybe the way I'm going about this is all wrong, if so please tell me of a different way.

The problem is spaces. Replacing " " with "\ " causes file not found. If the path OR the filename has a space the below tends to work, but if they both have space(s) bash breaks it up into multiple arguments.

```
echo;
for d in */; do
  for fn in "$d"/*; do
    if [ $(sha512sum "$fn" | cut -d ' ' -f 1) == $(ssh user@host sha512sum "/home/user/somepath/$fn" | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ];
      then echo deleting "$fn"; ssh user@host rm "/home/user/somepath/$fn"; echo gone;
      else echo diff;
    fi;
  done;
  echo;
done
```

Same space problem, but this one check for file even existing on remote before hashing locally to speed up. This way I should be able to compare local1 to remote1 and remote2 more easily (like if you copied stuff from both remote1 and remote2 into local1).

```
echo;
for d in */; do
  for fn in "$d"/*; do
    if [[ $(ssh user@host test "/home/user/somepath/$fn") ]];
      then if [ $(sha512sum "$fn" | cut -d ' ' -f 1) == $(ssh user@host sha512sum "/home/user/somepath/$fn" | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ];
        then echo deleting "$fn"; ssh user@host rm "/home/user/somepath/$fn"; echo gone;
        else echo diff;
      fi;
      else echo remote dont got $fn;
    fi;
  done; echo;
done
```

Not sure if it matters or not, but say dir inside targetdir is exdir1 and filename is exfile.ext, it prints out "exdir1//exfile.ext" when it echos $fn. It works with the //, but maybe it has some impact on the space problem.

Comment: Read [ssh eats my word boundaries!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/096)

Comment: Not sure what you are exactly doing but take a look at [tag:rsync] and see if it can help. It's for sync'ing files between hosts and its algorithm is very efficient. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ssh commands, change `"/home/user/somepath/$fn"` to `" '/home/user/somepath/$fn' "`. The space between `"` and `'` is optional which is only to improve readibility.

You can try playing with it like:

```
ssh user@host touch " '/tmp/foo    bar' "
ssh user@host ls    " '/tmp/foo    bar' "
ssh user@host rm    " '/tmp/foo    bar' "
```

Comment: Got it working applying this to the second one in the post (think had to tweak a few parts too). But had to migrate to "find ... | while read fn" to get subdirs

`user=username; host=hostaddr; remoteTarget=/home/user/somepath echo; find . -type f | while read fn; do if $(ssh -n $user@$host test -f "'$remoteTarget/$fn'"); then if [ $(sha512sum "$fn" | cut -d ' ' -f 1) == $(ssh -n $user@$host sha512sum "'$remoteTarget/$fn'" | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ]; then echo X deleting $fn; ssh -n $user@$host rm "'$remoteTarget/$fn'"; echo gone; else echo ??? diff; fi; else echo -_- remote dont got $fn; fi; done`